# Android background service for calling a webservice every 5 minutes

Tags: android, service

I need a background service for my android app that every 5 minutes calls a webservice and stores the received data in a database . The webservice is already fully functional and every 5 minutes has new data available. And also how can I make this service make the webcalls at precise times, I need it to make the calls at certain minutes and seconds.

For example it has to make the calls at 12:05:05 and then at 12:10:05 and after that at 12:15:05 and so on. The reason for this is because the webservice has new data at precise times and I want to get it as soon as it is available. What couldbe the best solution for this problem?

Comment: start from reading `AlarmManager` docs

Answer (score 0):

You can learn the fundamentals of services from [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/components/services.html). And then learn about `REST` web services from [here](http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/android-restful-webservice-tutorial-part-1/).

Also learn about Databases in Android from [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html).

Comment: sorry if it's not very specific .part of the app is done , and the webservice is already running . I just need a way to call it every 5 minutes

Comment: Then, edit the question , show your code, and where you need help. That's the correct way!

Comment: Hi there. Please note that answers are not for commentary about how to use the site - it's great to offer that sort of help, but it is better placed in the comments under the question.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the AlarmManager to start an IntentService which calls the webservice.

[Here](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Starting-Background-Services#using-with-alarmmanager-for-periodic-tasks) is a good explanation of this technique.

Comment: Thank you , this seems to be useful , I will have a look at it

Answer (score 0):

you have to used below code for calling method every 5 minutes.

```
// some time when u want to run
Date when = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());    

try{
   Intent someIntent = new Intent(someContext,MyReceiver.class); // intent to be launched

   // note this could be getActivity if you want to launch an activity
   PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
        context, 
        0, // id, optional
        someIntent, // intent to launch
        PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT); // PendintIntent flag

   AlarmManager alarms = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(
        Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

   alarms.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
        when.getTime(),
        AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES,
        pendingIntent); 

}catch(Exception e){
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```